# I have image (6000*6000) resolute. Is it the same :resizing it to (1000*1000) then resizing to (512*512) and resizing it to(512*512) directly？

Tags: python, image, image-processing, computer-vision, image-resizing

I have about 200GB+ image (about 6000*6000) data on a server. For the portable reason I wish I could resize (cv2) it to (1000*1000), then transfer the data to the other cloud then reize to (512*512) and do some simple classification tasks. The resizing will save me a lot of life. I am just wondering by doing this, would the data lose some information other than resizing 6000*6000 directly to 512*512?

The result should be different, but I don't know how will it affect my model accuracy.

```
img2= cv2.resize(img, (1000, 1000))
img3=cv2.resize(img, (512, 512))
img4=cv2.resize(img2, (512, 512))
img3==img4

array([[[ True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True],
        ...,
        [ True, False,  True],
        [ True, False,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True]],

       [[ True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True],
        ...,
        [ True,  True, False],
        [ True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True]],

       [[ True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True],
        ...,
        [ True, False,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True]],

       ...,

       [[ True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True],
```

Comment: Are you not able to test this?

Comment: Recommendation: Reside directly to 512x512, but smooth the input image before resizing (MATLAB `imresize` uses "Antialiasing" filter by default, and OpenCV doesn't). You need a large smoothing filter, and I don't know how to determine the size of it.

Comment: I did test it, the values are different. But I just wondering will this affect my model

Comment: Technically, two-step image resizing will lose some detail, but for image classification it should not make a big difference. For performance reasons, resizing in a single step might be preferable, but the overhead of the additional resize step isn't high.

Comment: Why not resize directly to 512x512 on the first server before transferring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you lose information.

Imagine you have a 4 x 4 image:

```
xxxx
xoxo
xxxx
xoxo
```

The example image is binary. Now you change the resolution to 2 x 2. Blocks, such as

```
xx
xo
```

need to be assigned either `x` or `o` in the new raster defined by the new resolution, so they change to `x`. Result is a new 2 x 2 image:

```
xx
xx
```

Now you change it back to a resolution of 4 x 4. There is however no longer any information on any `o` avaiable in the 2 x 2 image, so scaling back results in:

```
xxxx
xxxx
xxxx
xxxx
```

which is clearly different.

This is a trivial example, how much data loss occurs depends on the implementation of the format, specifically how data is respresented and stored. But in general - yes, there is obviously loss of information.

As a proposal - depending on what you need to do, you could instead send chuncks of the image to the server, do your classification on those, receive the result, send the next chunck and so on. Of course if you are looking to classify an object that spans the entire image, then this will not work.

Comment: I would suggest to do some preprocessing on the large images and find the interesting parts without any classification, this way you get a lot of smaller bounding boxes of the image with classifiable objects on them.